# Double type Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, double

I'm new about Neo4j, I do this (and other create for the relationship)

```
create (p:person {id:'1', name: 'Name', age: 75, vn_brain: 1270.373})
```

then I tried:

```
MATCH (n:person)-[lvn:LINKED_VN]->(vn) where lvn.VN_brain>30.00 RETURN n,lvn,vn LIMIT 5
```

I get this:

```
Error: Don't know how to compare that. Left: [3.9321] (double[]); Right: 30.0 (Double)
```

then I tried:

```
Error: Expected a String or Number, got: [D@68525b91
```

My question is: How can  I manage double in Neo4J?With point or with comma? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the real issue lies in the fact that `VN_brain` attribute of **at least one** instance of `LINKED_VN` relationship is an **array** of doubles.

Please check this in your data set, fix the anomaly and try again.